# Inbox properties on Outlook 2003 folder shows - 退ꢐ鑓i駘㡩詧뭩趉땩趓䝩駙兩贶坩駙i

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2003, special-characters

I'm not sure why, but when seeing the properties of a custom folder in a created PST data file, I see:

The Inbox folder having as a description as :

```
退ꢐ鑓i駘㡩詧뭩趉땩趓䝩駙兩贶坩駙i
```

Another one had:

```
退邐䬰昉䯠昉䩼昉
```

[image]

Comment: Perhaps you're attached to a Chinese-language Exchange server install? We need more information, right now it's not much of a question. :)

Comment: from google translate  chinese:     Back ꢐ Soldering rod i tired 㡩 Cha 뭩 Ju 땩 Duo 䝩 Fuliangkuanggan Boo i

Comment: lol - I didnt think of translating it, but thanks! I'm not sure where it came from. Its a local PST, not tied to any Exchange server (I dont have any Exchange server tie-up at all). Could be some virus artifact?

Comment: 退鑓駘㡩詧趉趓䝩駙兩贶坩駙

Answer (score 1):

Here's output from my *[Alt KeyCode Finder](https://superuser.com/a/1047961/376602)* script for your string:

```
Ch Unicode    Alt?    CP    IME    Alt   Alt0    IME 0405/cs-CZ; CP852; ANSI 1250
 退  U+9000   36864          …0…                  CJK Ideograph 
 ꢐ  U+A890   43152        …144…                  Saurashtra Letter Oo
 鑓  U+9453   37971         …83…                  CJK Ideograph 
 i   U+0069     105        …105…    105   0105    Latin Small Letter I
 駘  U+99D8   39384        …216…                  CJK Ideograph 
 㡩  U+3869   14441        …105…                  CJK Ideograph Extension A 
 詧  U+8A67   35431        …103…                  CJK Ideograph 
 □   U+BB69   47977        …105…                  Hangul Syllable Mieum Weo Thieuth
 趉  U+8D89   36233        …137…                  CJK Ideograph 
 □   U+B569   46441        …105…                  Hangul Syllable Ssangtikeut Ya Kiyeok
 趓  U+8D93   36243        …147…                  CJK Ideograph 
 䝩  U+4769   18281        …105…                  CJK Ideograph Extension A 
 駙  U+99D9   39385        …217…                  CJK Ideograph 
 兩  U+5169   20841        …105…                  CJK Ideograph 
 贶  U+8D36   36150         …54…                  CJK Ideograph 
 坩  U+5769   22377        …105…                  CJK Ideograph 
 駙  U+99D9   39385        …217…                  CJK Ideograph 
 i   U+0069     105        …105…    105   0105    Latin Small Letter I
```

I guess that at least all [Hangul](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hangul) characters as well as [Saurashtra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saurashtra_language) and [Latin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin_script) letters are simply truncated Unicode from *CJK Unified Ideographs Extension B* to [Basic Multilingual Plane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_(Unicode)) codepoints as follows:

- `ꢐ   U+A890 <- U+2A890`
- `i   U+0069 <- U+20069`
- `□   U+BB69 <- U+2BB69`     [(character is properly rendered at link)](http://unicode.scarfboy.com/?s=U%2B2BB69)
- `□   U+B569 <- U+2B569`

Your string *might* be as follows `退鑓駘㡩詧趉趓䝩駙兩贶坩駙` but I can't guarantee that above list contains **all** such truncation.

Note that rendered `□  U+25A1` *White Square* is simply a replacement character…