# Windows: Alt + 236 doesn't produce the infinity symbol: what's wrong?

Tags: windows, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-layout

I'd like to be able to type different math symbols using alt + number keyboard. However, I'm having some problems. For instance, they ([1](http://www.rapidtables.com/math/symbols/infinity_symbol/infinity-symbol-alt-code.htm),[2](http://fsymbols.com/signs/infinity/)) suggest that the infinity symbol should be produced by `alt+236`; but when I try it, I get `ь` which is a Cyrillic letter. I sort of could understand this when I have Russian keyboard layout, but this happens in English layout, too. Is there something I'm doing wrongly? Some configuration that I can change?

Comment: What language packs do you have installed.  I wasn't able to reproduce

Comment: @Ramhound I'm on Windows 10, and I've got English (US) and Russian languages installed

Comment: Try with only one language pack installed.

Comment: @Ramhound looks like Windows doesn't allow me to unistall Russian pack. Where do you suggest to set that? I've tried ~Parameters → Time and language → Region and language ; and also Control Panel → Language, in both "Remove" button is inactive and there's nothing like "switch off".

Comment: Well you should be able to

Comment: @Ramhound not necessarily: after updating to Win 10 some options are not managable, they are controled by Microsoft (not sure why and if that will expire at some point)

Comment: Removing language isn't one of those controlled features

Comment: Related: [description of Windows Alt+x codes](http://superuser.com/a/1047961/376602).