# Can I input "å" using the alt + numpad (or other) method on windows with "Latin-2 - Central European languages" encoding page?

Tags: windows, keyboard, character-encoding

As you can see. There is no "å" here: http://www.ascii-codes.com/cp852.html

Is there a (hopefully non-invasive) method for me to insert it? (crtl+V does not count.)

Comment: You will have to use a different language pack keyboard layout to achieve this

Comment: @Ramhound I'm using CP 852 as my default language and the character can be typed and displayed correctly.

Comment: What in the world is "cp 852" having looked at the list of language packs you can download that makes no sense

Answer (score 2):

If you use [Polish (214) keyboard layout](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-gb/globalization/keyboards/kbdpl.html): <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>5</kbd><kbd>a</kbd> or equivalent <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>5</kbd><kbd>a</kbd>.

Explanation: <kbd>AltGr</kbd> or equivalent <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd> activates *hidden* [dead keys](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keyboard_layout#Dead_keys) (in orange on next picture):

[image: Polish (214) keyboard layout]

Why [DavidPostill's answer](https://superuser.com/a/1086625/376602) does not work for you although works for him:

- in short: Windows <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> codes strongly depend on *system locale* which supposedly differs from his one);
- fully explained here: [Full description of Windows Alt+x codes](https://superuser.com/a/1047961/376602).

You could still take advantage from Windows <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>0x</kbd> codes: if you switch keyboard layout to any of *`US & Western Eu`* or *`Baltic`* or *`Turkic`* or *`Vietnamese`* input method, then <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>0229</kbd> would produce `å` *Latin Small Letter A With Ring Above*.

This would work even in `cmd` **regardless** of currently active code page `chcp`.

Answer (score 0):

#### Is there a (hopefully non-invasive) method for me to insert it

Assuming the code page is 852, as referenced in your link, you can use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>134</kbd> to type the <kbd>å</kbd> character.

Example in a `cmd` shell:

> [image]

---

#### Further Reading

- [Alt Codes, Shortcuts, HTML Codes for Special Characters](http://fontmeme.com/alt-codes-shortcuts-html-codes-for-special-characters/)

Comment: Unforunately (as it is in the link I attached in the 1st post), I end up with ć instead.

Comment: @Arsen Hmm. Can you try `chcp` in a `cmd` shell and see what your code page actually is?

Comment: It gives: 
`Aktywna strona kodowa: 852`

Comment: @Arsen Weird. So effectively the same code page, giving different characters ...

Comment: @DavidPostill Code page does not matter, see [my answer](http://superuser.com/a/1089958/376602) please.