# How to enter Chinese character U+6C41 with Windows input?

Tags: windows, input-languages, chinese

[Character U+6C41](http://www.unicode.org/cgi-bin/GetUnihanData.pl?codepoint=%E6%B1%81) looks like

[image]

or

[image]

and spelled as zhī.

But when I am entering `zhi` in Windows, then nothing similar appears:

[image]

Can I hint Windows somehow about tone or something?

**UPDATE**

The question is general. Suppose I don't know Unicode of the character and just using input method. I know only what is required to use input method, i.e. pinyin.

Answer (score 0):

You could use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> feature in Unicode-aware applications like Microsoft Word you can insert Unicode characters by typing the hex value of the character then typing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> (this means press <kbd>x</kbd> letter while holding <kbd>Alt</kbd> key).

For instance, in Sticky Notes:

[image: alt+x example]

Read more in [Insert Unicode characters via the keyboard](https://superuser.com/a/47424/376602) or [How to enter Unicode characters in Microsoft Windows](http://www.fileformat.info/tip/microsoft/enter_unicode.htm) as well as [this my answer](https://superuser.com/a/1047961/376602).