# Output "LATIN LET­TER SMALL CA­PI­TAL M" with Alt-NumKeypad sequence?

Tags: keyboard, unicode

I need to output the Unicode character [LATIN LET­TER SMALL CA­PI­TAL M](http://unicode-search.net/unicode-namesearch.pl?term=m&.submit=Search) with its Alt-NumKeypad sequence (holding the Alt key and typing numbers on the keypad). Unfortunately, the respective Alt-NumKeypad sequence is not indicated in the above list.

So, which Alt-NumKeypad sequence outputs the "LATIN LET­TER SMALL CA­PI­TAL M"?

Comment: There are no Alt-NumKeypad sequences in the list you quote. You should be able to enter it using `CharMap.exe`, which is in every Windows NT-based system since at least 2000, though there is not always a link to it.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: Try holding <kbd>Alt</kbd> and typing `7437` on the numeric keypad.

Longer answer:
According to FileFormat.Info, one way you can [enter a unicode character on Windows](http://www.fileformat.info/tip/microsoft/enter_unicode.htm) is by holding down <kbd>Alt</kbd> and typing the *decimal* value of the unicode character code in the numeric keypad.  (This is "Method 3" listed on the linked page.)  For [`LATIN LET­TER SMALL CA­PI­TAL M`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1d0d/index.htm) the Unicode character code is `1D0D` in hexadecimal, which translates to 7437 decimal.

However, this method seems to depend on what code page you are using, and whether the application you are typing into is using a font that contains the character glyph you are typing.  I tried this method on Windows 10 to type into Microsoft Word 2013 with the font set to Arial and it worked. But, trying to type that same sequence into this answer using Chrome on the same machine results in a musical note: ♪   So your mileage may vary.

Comment: `Alt`+`7437` gives the same character as `Alt`+`13` i.e. `♪` _Eighth Note_ in any application which is not compiled as Unicode-aware, see output from `set /A 7437 % 256` and read my [Full description of Windows Alt+x codes](http://superuser.com/a/1047961/376602).