# I try to type alt codes like sigma Σ and infinite ∞ on Windows but I keep getting � (unrecognized character). How can I fix this?

Tags: windows, language, unicode, alt-code

I get exactly � at almost every alt code I type. "é" and most other latin alphabet characters seem fine, but the majority of punctuation, symbols, and some letters don't show up.

I'm on Windows 10. In my world & region language settings, it's set to "English (United States)" and checked "Beta: Use Unicode UTF-8 for worldwide language support". I'm not sure if they might conflict with the alt codes?

The following do not work, but is what I tried.

```
For Σ, I'm using Alt+228  
For ∞, I'm using Alt+236  
For é, I'm using Alt+0233
```

It doesn't matter where I type these, Notepad++, Microsoft Word (Times New Roman), Firefox, Chrome, etc., I still get the same result.

Comment: It's a beta; report your findings to MS.

Comment: 1. What app behaves as described? 2. What if you paste the `Σ∞` string directly? 3. Show the alt-codes you are using for `é`, `Σ` and `∞` characters.

Comment: @JosefZ All, Google Chrome, Microsoft Word, Notepad. If I paste them directly, it works out fine. I'll edit the post to include what alt codes I'm using

Comment: LaTeX was designed to overcome this. You could try that for symbols. Each application accepts utf-32 differently,it could be.

Comment: Recently I have written a small Powershell script (_Alt KeyCode Finder_) [`myCharMap.ps1`](http://superuser.com/a/1047961/376602) to see what characters you can enter using simple _alt codes_ in Windows. However, _IMHO_ the best page on this topic is [How to enter Unicode characters in Microsoft Windows](http://www.fileformat.info/tip/microsoft/enter_unicode.htm).

Comment: which software or computer window you are typing in? Even Beta cannot have such a problem. It seems more simpler like the font that is applicable there doesn't have these characters. What is the name of the font you see there? and encoding also?

Comment: @VSRawat Updated question. It doesn't matter where I type these, Notepad++, Microsoft Word, Firefox, Chrome, etc., I still get the same result. For Microsoft Word, I'm using Time News Roman. What do you mean encoding?

Comment: Could you please try downloading and installing Arial Unicode MS font and make that active font in all the software where you are trying to generate these characters by Alt codes. Arial Unicode MS is the font having biggest unicode character set of most of the scripts. It will be worth a try. It is huge font file some 23 MB compared to less than 1 MB of normal font files.

Comment: @VSRawat Hi I've download and installed the Arial Unicode MS and put it in Microsoft Word but I still get the same result. It seems the beta thing is simply not letting me to type certain alt codes so it gets turned into this Unicode character �, so all fonts show �