# Cannot type certain characters in PowerShell

Tags: windows-10, powershell

I've realised I can't type some non-ASCII characters in the PowerShell console, all of which work fine in good old *cmd.exe* and should be supported by the code pages involved (it's a Spanish Windows edition with Spanish as only keyboard layout):

- If I type `€` it prints `?`. When I hit enter I can see a normally looking euro sign in the error message:

  [image: Test with '€']
- If I type `Á` it doesn't print anything at all but I can print `á` just fine. Similarly, I can type lowercase `ñ` but not uppercase `Ñ`.

  [image: Test with 'Á' and <code>á</code>]
- Interestingly, if I use clipboard to paste those chars I can see *some* of them:

  [image: €ÁÑ]

I happens in every Windows 10 PCs I've tried, with every TTF font I've tried.

Console code page is 850:

[image: Current code page]

Both `[System.Console]::InputEncoding` and `[System.Console]::OutputEncoding` show the same output:

```
IsSingleByte      : True
BodyName          : ibm850
EncodingName      : Europa occidental (DOS)
HeaderName        : ibm850
WebName           : ibm850
WindowsCodePage   : 1252
IsBrowserDisplay  : False
IsBrowserSave     : False
IsMailNewsDisplay : False
IsMailNewsSave    : False
EncoderFallback   : System.Text.InternalEncoderBestFitFallback
DecoderFallback   : System.Text.InternalDecoderBestFitFallback
IsReadOnly        : True
CodePage          : 850
```

Any idea of where to start looking?

Comment: What about `$OutputEncoding`, `[System.Console]::OutputEncoding` and `[System.Console]::InputEncoding`?

Comment: @JosefZ I've edited the question.

Comment: Maybe `$OutputEncoding` shows `CodePage: 20127` (us-ascii)? Try changing it as `$OutputEncoding = [System.Console]::OutputEncoding`.

Comment: @JosefZ You're right about the first part, it shows `US-ASCII` (is that meant to be the default?). But changing it to match `[System.Console]::OutputEncoding` doesn't change anything and there doesn't seem to be a similarly named `$InputEncoding`.

Comment: I've had the chance of testing in a Windows Server 2012 machine via Remote Desktop and `Á` can be typed but `€` cannot. I have a strong feeling that it has never really worked at 100% but I didn't notice until I tried to set my full name in git credentials. Oh well...

Comment: Would the [`Alt+x` method](https://superuser.com/a/1047961/376602) work? For instance, `Á`=`Alt+0193`=`Alt+181`, `á`=`Alt+0225`=`Alt+160`, `Ñ`=`Alt+0209`=`Alt+165` and `ñ`=`Alt+0241`=`Alt+164` in your locale CP850/ACP1252.

Comment: @JosefZ Yes, that works :-!